# Opening GitHub Issues using Template via ReST calls

Tags: templates, github, github-api, issue-tracking

I'm trying to open github issues via ReST APIs and we have some templates that we normally use. I need to open issues on a repo and I need to use the template.. I could simply use the template code in the ReST call as body but it's long and with a lot of newlines and so on.
Is there a method to open issues using templates via ReST APIs?

I already tried

https://github.com/api/v3/repos/name/reponame/issues
with "template": "template-name.md" in the JSON body

and also

https://github.com/api/v3/repos/name/reponame/issues?template=template-name.md and then JSON body (without body)

but none of them works... any suggestion?

Comment: I also ran into this limitation, and used https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#get-repository-content to retrieve the issue template's content and https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/front_matter_parser to strip the metadata. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not possible at the moment